# URL conflict in django1.8 and DRF 2.4.8

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Project level urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [
url(r'^machines/api/', include('core.urls')),
url(r'', include('apps.api.urls')),
url(r'^machines', include('apps.machines.urls')),]
```

App level urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^user/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', core_view.ProfileEdit.as_view()),
url(r'^group/', core_view.GroupList.as_view()),
url(r'^groups/add/', core_view.GroupCreate.as_view()),]
```

when i hit 
http://localhost:8000/machines/api/groups/add

it is calling `GroupList` view instead of `GroupCreate`.
I am not getting any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current url list triggered `GroupList` on each url started with `group/`. You should add `$` at the end of GroupList pattern to limit url triggered by GroupList only with `group`:

```
url(r'^group/$', core_view.GroupList.as_view()),
url(r'^groups/add/', core_view.GroupCreate.as_view()),]
```